# "zsh: command not found" when running maestro on macOS

Tags: macos, maestro

In order to test my mobile app, I want to try [Maestro mobile](https://maestro.mobile.dev/).

Following the official documentation, I installed Maestro on my Mac (macOS 13.5.1, M1 chip) using the following command:

```
curl -Ls "https://get.maestro.mobile.dev" | bash
```

Then I wanted to test it out using the following command:

```
maestro download-samples
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: maestro
```

So I searched where is Maestro located on my Mac, so I can add it in the PATH, but I can't find it.

Do you know where is Maestro installed on macOS? Or how I can fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: The installer ends with "Please open a new terminal OR run the following in the existing one: [command to extend PATH]" - so you should check the console for that.

Comment: That's strange, when I launch the curl command, I got nothing in the terminal, not even error... But thanks for the tip!

Comment: Then the installation failed.

Comment: Note that `curl | bash` is a Really Bad Idea from a security perspective. Serious package managers sign their downloads so a server being broken into and having its files modified can be detected; you lose all that when you just directly invoke code straight off the download. I've written an answer on the topic over at [security.se]: [Is `curl ${something} | sudo bash` a reasonably safe installation method?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/213499/56587)

Answer (score 0):

For me, using the following command solved the problem (I used `zsh` instead of `bash`):

```
curl -Ls "https://get.maestro.mobile.dev" | zsh
```

I also needed to install [Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/).

Comment: I use zsh, also on an M1 mac, and the command with `| bash` works fine for me... I wonder if not having Java was the problem. Or, maybe you forgot to open a new terminal after installing?

Comment: Oh maybe (for Java), that could be the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

> That's strange, when I launch the curl command, I got nothing in the terminal, not even error...

I also got nothing in the terminal. Then I tried sudo to the command, an error message for the proxy was output.

```
% sudo curl -Ls "https://get.maestro.mobile.dev" | zsh
Password:
* Create distribution directories...
* Downloading...
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: xxxxxxxx
```

After disconnecting from the VPN and trying the command without sudo, the following message was output and the download starts.

```
% curl -Ls "https://get.maestro.mobile.dev" | zsh
* Create distribution directories...
* Downloading...
* ######################################################################## 100.0%
* Welcome to Maestro!
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and as @andrew suggested opening a new terminal after installing helped me. Just posting here if anyone comes across this issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35517918)